# problem while installing some python packages

Tags: python, yum, centos5, odoo

There is an issue while installing some of the packages for python. They show 'No package available' message while trying to do yum install . They are these: python-psycopg, python-reportlab, graphviz, python-psycopg2, pychart, pydot, python-lxml.

The OS is CentOS5.5, python2.4 and postgres8.x. Its for installing Openerp. Their forum was not of much help.

Any help on it is much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CentOS doesn't have as many packages as other distributions and some of them are old, too. Add the [EPEL repository](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL/FAQ#howtouse) and see if it has the necessarily packages.

The [python-reportlab](http://packages.sw.be/python-reportlab/) and [python-psycopg](http://packages.sw.be/python-psycopg/) packages are available in the [RPMforge repository](http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories/RPMForge). I would recommend installing packages from this repository only if they're not available in CentOS or EPEL. This can be done with *yum-priorities*.

Comment: HMG!!. I have no words to thank you. Had been at this for nearly 2 days trying to set it up. 5 of them from the above got installed. Now just 2 more to go. python-psycopg, python-reportlab

Comment: Unfortunately i need 2 more reputation to up vote your answer. :(

Comment: @zapping select the check mark under the number of votes.

Comment: Got the python-reportlab installed with easy_install reportlab. But python-psycopg does not cannot find what it the command for it.

Comment: @zapping: [python-psycopg2](http://ftp.astral.ro/mirrors/fedora/pub/epel/5/i386/python-psycopg2-2.0.14-1.el5.i386.rpm) should be available.

Comment: Its not python-psycopg2 but python-psycopg. python-psycopg2 was installable according to your advice and unfourtunately both are needed.

Comment: Thank you Cristian. Have ticked your answer. Had given a +1 also before. Have tried installing openerp. It got installed and setup alright but while starting the server. There is some error being shown in the try catch finally. Further checking found that it could be that a python version higher than 2.4 is required. Its on hold right now as got busy with another stuff.